# Boundedness and compactness of the subset in $(l^2,||.||)$

Tags: functional-analysis

To investigate boundedness and compactness of the following subset in $(ℓ^2,\|⋅\|)$.

$S\in l^2$.

$S:=\{{x=x_n\in l^2:\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty|x_n|^2\le1 }\}$

Is the following "proof"  is ok? If no, I would appreciate any hint.

**Boundedness:**

As $S$ is a closed unit ball, we note that a closed ball is a closed set.

To prove this, let $M=B_R(y)$ is a closed ball of radius $R$ around $y$. Let $x∈M^C$. Now, let $$r=d(x,y)−R>0\ \textit{and}\ z\in B_r(x).$$
Then
$$d(y,x)\leq d(y,z)+d(z,x) < d(y,z)+r \Rightarrow d(y,z)>R$$
Hence $z∉M$ and hence the open ball $B_r(x)$ is totally contained in $M^C$, hence $M^C$ is open and hence $M$ is closed.

**Compactness:**

Now, since we have  a convergent (sub)sequence in a closed set, it is going to converge to some point in the set itself, by definition of closed set.

Comment: Compactness is when any sequence has an accumulation point. If you start with a sequence that's already convergent, you can't infer compactness.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean $\sum |x_n|^2$ in the definition of $S$ there?

In any case, it is not compact. The "standard basis" of $\ell^2$, $\{e_j\} \subset S$ (where $e_j(i) = 0$ for all $i\neq j$ and $e_j(j) = 1$), and does not have a convergent subsequence (why?)